# Can a circuit produce a magnetic force on itself?

Tags: electromagnetism

Well I think that it is kind of obvious, because the magnetic force does not specify if the fiel is produced or not by the circuit that feels it, but I had never heard about "autoinduced forces" or anything like that. My full question is as follows:
A circuit with flowing current feels a force when it is surrounded by an external magnetic field. But ciurcuits on its own create magnetic fields, due to its current. A circuit can feel a magnetic force due to the magnetic fiel it creates?

Comment: google "self inductance".

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I know that circuits can cause self induced emfs (electromotive forces) but, in a similar way, can they apply a magnetic force on them selves?

Comment: Sure they can! Light has momentum, and you can design a circuit that emits radiation in some direction. This will push the circuit in the other direction.

Comment: (Throwing radiation out to infinity is the only way you can achieve this -- otherwise, it would be like pulling yourself up by your own bootstraps.)